# Is it possible to batch-export fcurves of specific animations?

Tags: export, graph-editor, fcurves

I am attempting to make what is in effect a "sound sculpture". I am using the Bizualizer addon, and after baking the fcurves, want to export them so that they can be processed to be used in sculpting. I have [located a script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/69101) which does the basics of what i want, but not to specifics. This script runs on the active object only, ergo only one object at a time. Additionally, it always exports all of the fcurves of the given object, which means a bloat of extraneous data. In my use case, the only fcurve i want exported is *Y Scale*.

Is it possible to run a script which exclusively locates Y Scale fcurves? And if so, is it possible to have the script locate *all* of these within the selection? If not the latter, then is it possible to have the script successively make each selected object the active object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assembled a script that does exactly what i wanted it to do. It is based on the one linked in the initial submission.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
selected_objects = context.selected_objects

with open("output.svg", "a") as f:
    print("<svg>", file=f)

    for o in selected_objects:
        context.view_layer.objects.active = o

        for fcurve in o.animation_data.action.fcurves:
            if fcurve.data_path == 'scale' and fcurve.array_index == 1:
                print("<path name=\"%s\" d=\"M" % o.name, file=f)
                for kfp in fcurve.keyframe_points:
                    #print("\t\"", end="", file=f)
                    vals = []
                    for prop in ["handle_left", "co"]:
                        co = getattr(kfp, prop)
                        vals.append("%.4f,%.4f" %  co[:])
                    print("\t%s" % " S ".join(vals), file=f)
                print("\" /> ", file=f)

    print ("</svg>", file=f)
```

This script finds the *Y Scale* fcurves for all selected objects, and exports them, as a batch, into a single file (which i have designated as an SVG). I also adjusted the original code so that the format the output follows will be a syntactically valid SVG file. Output looks like this:

```
<svg>
<path name="bz_bar0" d="M
    0.6667,0.0000 S 1.0000,0.0000
    1.6667,0.0000 S 2.0000,0.0000
    2.6667,0.0004 S 3.0000,0.0013
    3.6667,0.0034 S 4.0000,0.0038
    4.6667,0.0039 S 5.0000,0.0071
    5.6667,0.0167 S 6.0000,0.0187
    [etc]
" />
```

This will adequately capture the shape of the f-curve. The S path command can be used rather than C since all handles on one of Blender's fcurves are mirrored.